# List box shows blank line space below each element

Tags: php, mysql, html

Listbox shows blank line space below each element. Increased the width also but still the blank line appears. I have attached the screenshot for reference.I have attached the code file. I am using a function to select the records from the dropdown list . The dropdown list is working but blank record shows below every value which is shown in the screenshot.

```
<?php
$selected = '';

function get_options($select) {
    $categories = array('Information Technology' => 1, 'Management' => 2);
    $options = '';
    while (list($k, $v) = each($categories)) {
        if ($select == $v) {
            $options .= '<option value="' . $v . '" selected>' . $k . '<option>';
        } else {
            $options .= '<option value="' . $v . '" >' . $k . '<option>';
        }
    }
    return $options;
}

require_once('dbconnect.php');
if (isset($_POST['categories'])) {
    $selected = $_POST['categories'];
    echo $selected;
}
if ($selected == 1) {
    $selectedcat = 'Information Technology';
    $selectsql = "SELECT * FROM courses where ccategory='$selectedcat'";
} else
if ($selected == 2) {
    $selectedcat = 'Management';
    $selectsql = "SELECT * FROM courses where ccategory='$selectedcat'";
} else {
    $selectsql = "SELECT * FROM courses";
}

//require_once('dbconnect.php');
include('header-basic-light.php');

//$selectsql="SELECT * FROM courses";
$res = (mysqli_query($con, $selectsql));

if (!mysqli_query($con, $selectsql)) {
    die(mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_close($con);
//header('Location:index.php');
?>
<HTML>
    <head>
        <title>"View Information"</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container"> 
            <div class="row">
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
                    <label for="categories">Select the Category : </label>
                    <select name="categories" style="width:250px;" onchange="this.form.submit();">

                    <?php echo get_options($selected); ?>
                    </select>
                </form>

                <h2>View Information</h2>
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>cname</th>
                        <th>start_date</th>
                        <th>duration</th>
                        <th>Remarks</th>
                        <th>Options</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $r['cno']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $r['cname']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $r['start_date']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $r['duration']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $r['remarks']; ?></td>
                            <?php
                            if ($r['ccategory'] == 'Information Technology') {
                                $catnum = 1;
                            }
                            if ($r['ccategory'] == 'Management') {
                                $catnum = 2;
                            }
                            ?>
                            <td><a href="loadpage.php?id=<?php echo $catnum; ?>">Details&nbsp&nbsp</a>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </table>
                </body>
                </html>
```

[Listbox screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhUs8.jpg)

Comment: could you please put a var_dump($options); before the return $options line in your function and paste the output here?

Comment: additionally, make sure you sanitize the input vars as this script is vulnerable to sql injection in it's current state :)

Comment: _Suggestion:_ A more straight forward way to iterate the options would be: `foreach ($categories as $k => $v)` instead of your over-complicated `while`-loop (which basically just is a less efficient way to emulate a foreach).

Comment: It shows Information Technology , blankline, management,, ",Information Technology,blank line,Management..One quote came  in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st :** You missed forward slash in option close tag `</option>`

```
$options.='<option value="'.$v.'" selected>'.$k.'</option>';
```

**2nd :** Try to use prepared statement to avoid sql injection .

Comment: What a mistake! It took me a while to find out :P

Comment: Yes. I have overlooked.